# Read .db file in Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using Mosquitto Project (http://mosquitto.org), this is my mosquitto.conf

> persistence_file mosquitto.db
>
> persistence_location C:/var/lib/mosquitto/

After running, I have got mosquitto.db, but I can't open it. I'm trying open with Microsoft Excel, sqlitebrowser_200_b1_win but it's not working. 
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

I just answered this same question on the mosquitto answers tracker:

https://answers.launchpad.net/mosquitto/+question/217523

> The mosquitto.db file holds internal persistence information on client
>   subscriptions and retained messages. It isn't intended for use outside
>   of mosquitto. There is no guarantee that it is up to date information.
>
> Having said that, if you are interested in looking at the file then
>   the source file to look at is src/persist.c. There is also a program
>   to print the file contents in a more readable manner - you should
>   compile src/db_dump/db_dump.c.

mosquitto.db is an internal file and has nothing to do with sql.

Comment: From Where I can get  src/db_dump/db_dump.c. file?

Comment: @kavie in the source code bundle for mosquitto perhaps? https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/src/db_dump

Comment: yeah .it is there,I'm from Java background.I don't know how to use this.Can u help me for this?

Answer (score 9):

To read mosquitto.db file do these steps

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto
cd mosquitto/apps/db_dump
make
sudo ./mosquitto_db_dump /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db
```

You'll then get output like

```
DB_CHUNK_SUB:
        Length: 54
        Client ID: <Your Client ID>
        Topic: <topic>
        QoS: 0
        Subscription ID: 0
        Options: 0x00
```

Or

```
DB_CHUNK_MSG_STORE:
        Length: 285
        Store ID: 28935676
        Source Port: 1883
        Source MID: 4027
        Topic: <topic>
        QoS: 1
        Retain: 0
        Payload Length: 190
        Expiry Time: 0
        Payload: <Payload>
```

Comment: hi, is it possible to get the definition of all those categories DB_CHUNK_MSG_STORE, DB_CHUNK_SUB, what does it means we coudnt find any documents related to that