# When I open mosquitto.db with sqlite it gives an error 'File is encrypted or it is not a database'

Tags: sqlite, mqtt, mosquitto

I know there are fixed like creating databases in php,android but in this case it is generated by mosquitto so how can I see it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a sqllite db.

Why do you want to open the mosquitto db file? It doesn't hold anything of use to a end user.

Messages are only held in this DB while they are being delivered.

Please see the following answer for more detail

[Read .db file in Mosquitto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018386/read-db-file-in-mosquitto)

Comment: Where can see the retained messages by the broker to do analysis on data.

Comment: You don't, if you really must then look at the mosquito source code and write your own tool to open the file.

Comment: Thanks that will help too. I got another solution in mind I will log data into the database in callback in java.After subscribing to # and analyzing entries.