# Verify/check Mosquitto.Db data from mosquitto or any cli or freeware package

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Is there any way to verify mosquitto.db data from database file?

I took backup of mosquitto.db file and copied into my desired backup location, but during restore of mosquitto.db is there way to verify backed up data using any cli or mqttx client?

Comment: From [the docs](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) "The data will be written to disk when mosquitto closes and also at periodic intervals as defined by autosave_interval" so unless you are shutting Mosquitto down it's likely that the `.db` file is incomplete anyway. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024101/11810946) from the author for more info - what do you intend to do with the backup?.

Answer (score 2):

The database is not intended to be human readable.

It holds the following information:

- Inflight QOS 1/2 messages
- including messages for offline clients with persistent sessions
- Session information for clients

There is a tool included in the mosquitto source (but not build by default) that can open the file for the curious.

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/apps/db_dump

Comment: Thanks for the quick prompt.

Is there any way to verify database which we backed up (mosquitto.db) after restore (mosquitto.db) to persistent location of mosquitto ?

Comment: If the tool opens the file, then it's probably OK, but there is no other tests. IIRC mosquitto writes a new copy and renames when updating the file, so there shouldn't be a way to corrupt the file (assuming no disc space problems).

Comment: Is there any other way to take backup of MQTT data in JSON file so later on can we import during restore or something ?

Comment: No, this is a pure binary dump of the internal state of the broker, as I said it is NOT intended to be human readable.

Comment: It would be great if you can suggest other approach for backup and restore Mqtt.if you have any.